# jqGrid: Delete, edit and expand icon/click while creating a new row (inline)

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Creating a new row (inline) the icons to delete and to edit the row are displayed. Furthermore the row expand icon is shown (while there can't be any details (subgrid as a grid)). How to get the icons right/disabled/removed? In case of an insert it would be nice to have the save and cancel operations available on the row editing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the afterInsertRow event to accomplish this. For example if you don't want the row to be expanded and you don't want the edit delete icons do the following:

```
  function AfterInsertRow(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
      if (rowid == '0') {
          var row = $('#0');
          row.find('a:first').remove();
          row.find('div:first').remove();
      }
  }
```

Assuming the inserted row has the value 0.